# How to use Dynamic Instantiation with ICriteria in Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hbm

I know that you can do this easily with HQL using the following syntax:

```
"select new ItemRow(item.id, item.name) from ..."
```

In this example, the ItemRow need not be a persistent class that has its own mapping class.

But how can we accomplish the same using ICriteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that is equivalent to...

```
.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.Property("item.id"), "id")
    .Add(Projections.Property("item.name"), "name"))
.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ItemRow>())
.List<ItemRow>();
```

Comment: Let me try that, I'll get back to you.